# Blocked roads with pgRouting

Tags: pgrouting, routing

What is the best practice to manage temporary blocked roads (works on the road) with pgRouting?

Is there a dedicated feature adding exception?

If not, i give an heavy weight to the edge?

Comment: maybe add an attribute **blocked** and filter first for non blocked roads and than execute the query

Comment: I would agree that adding an attribute to your roads that would describe the blocked status then using that to update the COST (assuming you're using a COST value...)